# Is there a list of forbidden method names for Grails domain objects?

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

Often as I add a helper method to a domain object I get an error when compiling which resolves to "x property is not found".  This seems to happen for methods name `getX`, `setX`, and also recently `isX`.  Is there a list of name forms that I should avoid?  Is there a way to annotate or otherwise label these methods so Grails doesn't confuse them with auto properties?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Grails autodetects properties and assumes that they're persistent. Public fields in Groovy create a getter and setter under the hood so getters are assumed to be associated with persistent fields.

But if you want a helper method that starts with 'get' or 'is' but isn't a getter for a persistent field, you have two options. One is to use the `transients` list - see http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/transients.html

The other option is to declare the return value as `def`. Since it's not typed (def is an alias for Object) Hibernate can't persist it since it doesn't know what data type to use, so it's ignored.

My preference is the `transients` list because I would rather have self-documenting methods where it's obvious what they do, what parameter types they accept, and what they return.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea of common list - it's too diverse. Convention methods are added by different parts of Groovy and Grails:

- Groovy convention about property getters/setters is very basic thing. It's impossible have a `getX()` method and not have read access to `x` property.
- [Grails domain class dynamic methods](http://www.grails.org/DomainClass+Dynamic+Methods) and [Domain class convention properties](http://grails.org/doc/1.0.3/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/DefaultGrailsDomainClass.html) are specific to Grails domain classes;
- [Same for controllers](http://www.grails.org/Controller+Dynamic+Methods), and so on;
- Groovy convention about property getters/setters, including [`methodMissing`, `propertyMissing`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+methodMissing+and+propertyMissing), `$staticMethodMissing`, `getProperty`, `properties` and so on;
- Groovy adds a number of `as<Type>()` methods, like `asInteger()`;
- different plugins could inject more convention methods.

To access declared field, not getter/setter, use [java field access operator](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-Javafield%28.@%29).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem, you can use transient !

```
static transients = ['feildName']
```